# Firestore cloud listener, not working on collection inside collection

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am setting up a program which uses the Admin Sdk from Firebase, it needs to be able to update on any changes or documents added on a collection. The problem is that it doesn't update when it is a collection/document/collection/document/collection.

my code is this. (doesn't work)

```
import time
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from google.cloud import firestore
def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for doc in doc_snapshot:
        print(u'Received document snapshot: {}'.format(doc.id))

cred = credentials.Certificate('cred.json')
default_app=firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.Client()
doc_ref = db.collection('company').document('main').collection('restaurant').document('info').collection('orders')
doc_watch = doc_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
#for this example i will use a while (it works too)
while True:
   time.sleep(1)
   print ('processing...')
```

but it works with this doc_ref

```
doc_ref = db.collection('orders')
```

and also like this

```
db.collection('company').document('main').collection('restaurant')
```

am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Firestore clients do not provide a single API to listen to all documents in a collection and in its nested subcollections.  Firestore clients can listen to the results of a query, which must be made against a single collection.

Documents in subcollections are not actually part of any "parent" collections.  Each subcollection is its own independent collection, and requires its own query to listen to.  So, if you want to know if any document in a collection or any nested subcollection changes, you will need to add a listener on each independent collection, no matter where it lives.  This implies that you also must know the names of all the subcollections - there are no wildcards for queries.

Comment: if i understood correctly, i should do something like:                

firstCol_ref=   db.collection('company')
firstCol_listener = firstCol_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
secCol_ref= firstCol_listener.document('main').collection('restaurant')
secCol_listener = firstCol_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
thirdCol_ref =  firstCol_listener.document('infoDoc').collection('orders')
thirdCol_listener =  thirdCol_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)